Angular Lifecycle hooks?
Just wanted to know if I don't implement any lifecycle hooks explicitly does Angular framework call it implicitly?
For Eg: If I am not using @input in component does ngOnChanges will get triggered implicitly by angular as it gets executed before ngOnInit? and if I am usling @input but don't write ngOnChanges  then will it get called implicitly ?  Same question for other Hooks?
Thanks in advance.

If you don't implement a given lifecycle hook, then there is nothing for Angular to call. When the event happens, no function gets called.
This won't stop angular from doing its job though. Components will still initialize, whether or not you implement an ngOnInit function; @inputs will still change their value if told to by a parent component, whether or not you write an ngOnChanges, etc.

Lets be specific about ngOnChanges. If I am not using @input property and haven't explicitly call  ngOnChanges will Angular itself will call ngOnChanges implicitly? even though there is nothing for ngOnchanges to check upon?
